# Filter after group_by in r

Tags: r, filter, group-by

I want to filter some data after I use `group_by` for variable year `yr`.
I have the year when the loans are issued `yr`, `status` of the loan and the `amount`. I want to find the total number of loans issued, how many of these have the status "Changed off" and the amount of the loans with status "Charged off" for **each `yr`**

What I have tried is

```
    data %>% select(status, yr, amount)%>%
                     group_by(yr) %>%
                     summarise(Nr_of_laons=count(),
                            nr_charged_off=as.numeric(nrow(filter(status=="Charged Off"))))
```

it must be supper easy but I couldn't find the mistake.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `group_by`, get the count with `n()` and get the `sum` of logical expression

```
data %>%
     group_by(yr) %>%
     summarise(Nr_of_loans = n(), 
               nr_charged_off= sum(status=="Charged Off"),
               Amt_loans = sum(amount[status== "Charged Off"]))
```

Comment: @Erick  I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: I was using count() fnc instead of n(). With count was giving the following error "Evaluation error: argument "x" is missing, with no default."

Comment: @Erick `count` needs a data.frame as input.  It won't work inside `summarise`.  the way to use os `data %>% count(yr)`

Comment: Any suggestion how to find the amount of these loans with status "Charged off"?